# Adding Pop Up Window when New Page Opens on Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, web-parts

I am currently redesigning a page on SharePoint and I am having trouble with adding in a pop up window when a new page opens. I want the user to click into a new page and when the new page opens, a pop up window appears with a message.

I am fairly new to SharePoint and hence why I am finding this difficult.

I have seen solutions using JQUERY, Javascript, HTML etc but not sure how to exactly implement it using SharePoint (on .aspx page)

I would like to avoid JQUERY and Javascript at all costs as they are not my strongest areas.

Is it a case of adding a new Web Part and embedding the code in there or?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it something like <a href="#" target="_blank"> can you use ? But this will open a new window not a pop up!

Comment: Ye I had previously tried embedding code such as above but it only showed wording with a link which didnt open anything. I need to have a pop up message open when the user opens the page

Comment: Can you show something visually, what you are expecting? I think you bit confused between tooltip, popup window and new window.

Comment: I am looking for a pop-up window. So when the user opens a certain page, they will be prompt with a pop up message i.e. welcome.

Comment: @Ryan, what version of SharePoint are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Script Editor Webpart (Sharepoint 2013) Then add code given below

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#overlay, #popup').css('display', 'block');


  $('#overlay').click(function(){
    $('#overlay, #popup').css('display', 'none');
  });

 });
```

Add Content Editor webpart and then Add CSS and HTML there

```
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Here" />
 <div id="overlay"></div>
 <div id="popup"></div>
```

When comes to popup you can't completely avoid Javascript, Find complete code in Fiddle. (In fiddle example, instead of click add code in directly inside ready function)

http://jsfiddle.net/JRD06/sx0mjwe1/

or use this

https://fiddle.jshell.net/nikhilmangal/srg3gy26/light/

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript libraries included in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 include methods for easily creating and displaying dialog boxes in a standard way.

For this, you simply execute `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()`.

For example:

```js
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(showDialog,"sp.js");

function showDialog(){
    var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    dialogOptions.title = "Your Title Here!";
    var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
    dummyElement.innerHTML = "<h1>Your HTML Goes Here</h1>"
    dialogOptions.html = dummyElement;
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);    
}
```

To get the JavaScript to run when the page loads, you can embed it in a web part.

- In SharePoint 2010, save your JavaScript code into a text file (with `<script>` tags around it) and save it to a library on your SharePoint site, then add a Content Editor Web Part to the page where you want the code to run, and set the web part's "Content Link" property to the path of the text file.
- In SharePoint 2013, use the Script Editor web part to embed the desired JavaScript.